# C++ QT5 LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol (unit test)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to unit test my application but i wont get it work.

I habe 2 .pro files. One in my "main" project and one in "Unittest".

My Folder structure is :

```
offline_ip_adress_calculator
├───updater
│   └───updater
├───classes
│   ├───ip_calculator
│   └───threads
├───image
└───tests
    └───Unittest
        └───ip_calculator
```

Unittest .pro file:

```
TargetDirectory = C:\build\unit_test

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = $$TargetDirectory\debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\debug\.obj
    MOC_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\debug\.moc
    RCC_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\debug\.rcc
    UI_DIR =  $$TargetDirectory\debug\.ui
} else {
    DESTDIR = $$TargetDirectory\release
    OBJECTS_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\release\.obj
    MOC_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\release\.moc
    RCC_DIR = $$TargetDirectory\release\.rcc
    UI_DIR =  $$TargetDirectory\release\.ui
}

QT  += testlib
QT  += core


INSTALLS += target sources

CONFIG += c++11


TARGET = maintest

# Change this Path
INCLUDEPATH += X:/ip_adress_calculator/offline_ip_adress_calculator

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    qtestqstring.cpp \
    ip_calculator/qttestcomboxone.cpp \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    qtestqstring.h \
    ip_calculator/qttestcomboxone.h
```

My unit test class:

```
#ifndef QTTESTCOMBOXONE_H
#define QTTESTCOMBOXONE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest/QTest>


#include "classes/ip_calculator/comboxone.h"

class QtTestComboxOne : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne();

public:
    explicit QtTestComboxOne(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // QTTESTCOMBOXONE_H


#include "qttestcomboxone.h"

QtTestComboxOne::QtTestComboxOne(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}




void QtTestComboxOne::QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne()
{
    ComboxOne combox_one;

    combox_one.setCommunicationNumber(1);
    QCOMPARE(combox_one.calculate(QString("industrial_switch_1")), QString("10.0.20.2"));
}
```

ComboxOne class:

```
#ifndef COMBOXONE_H
#define COMBOXONE_H

#include "abstractipcalculator.h"

class ComboxOne  : public AbstractIpCalculator
{
public:
    ComboxOne();
    QString calculate(QString);

private:
    QString calculateOctetOne(QString);
    QString calculateOctetTwo(QString);
    QString calculateOctetThree(QString);
    QString calculateOctetFour(QString);
};

#endif // COMBOXONE_H
```

COmboxOne cpp:

```
#include "comboxone.h"

ComboxOne::ComboxOne()
{
    data_structure.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>("industrial_switch_1", "Industrial Switch I"));
}

QString ComboxOne::calculate(QString name)
{
    QString return_value;

    return_value.append(calculateOctetOne(name));
    return_value.append(".");
    return_value.append(calculateOctetTwo(name));
    return_value.append(".");
    return_value.append(calculateOctetThree(name));
    return_value.append(".");
    return_value.append(calculateOctetFour(name));

    return return_value;
}

QString ComboxOne::calculateOctetOne(QString name)
{
    return [...];
}

QString ComboxOne::calculateOctetTwo(QString name)
{
    [...]
    return QString::number(temp_res);
}

QString ComboxOne::calculateOctetThree(QString name)
{
    [...]
    return QString::number(temp_res);
}

QString ComboxOne::calculateOctetFour(QString name)
{
    [...]
    return QString("10");

}
```

AbstractIpCalculator

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H
#define ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPair>
#include <QQueue>


class AbstractIpCalculator
{
public:
    QQueue<QPair<QString,QString> > data_structure;

    AbstractIpCalculator();

    bool setParkNetzId(int index, int value);
    void setCommunicationNumber(int communication_number);
    virtual QString calculate(QString) = 0;

protected:
    QMap<int, int> park_netz_list;
    int communication_number;
    int getParkNetId();

    static const int bla_1 = 360;
    static const int bal_2 = 363;

private:
    virtual QString calculateOctetOne(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetTwo(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetThree(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetFour(QString) = 0;
};

#endif // ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H
```

Unit test Main

```
#include <QTest>
#include "qtestqstring.h"
#include "ip_calculator/qttestcomboxone.h"

int main()
{
    QTestQString string_test;
    QtTestComboxOne combox_one;

    QTest::qExec(&string_test);
    QTest::qExec(&combox_one);
}
```

I get this error messages:

```
qttestcomboxone.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QString __thiscall ComboxOne::calculate(class QString)" (?calculate@ComboxOne@@UAE?AVQString@@V2@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QtTestComboxOne::QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne(void)" (?QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne@QtTestComboxOne@@AAEXXZ)

qttestcomboxone.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall AbstractIpCalculator::setCommunicationNumber(int)" (?setCommunicationNumber@AbstractIpCalculator@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QtTestComboxOne::QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne(void)" (?QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne@QtTestComboxOne@@AAEXXZ)

qttestcomboxone.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall AbstractIpCalculator::setParkNetzId(int,int)" (?setParkNetzId@AbstractIpCalculator@@QAE_NHH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QtTestComboxOne::QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne(void)" (?QtTestCalculateIndustrialSwitchOne@QtTestComboxOne@@AAEXXZ)
```

I think the class "ComboxOne" can't find the parent class.

Comment: Have you actually written the code for `calculate`, `setCommunicationNumber` and `setParkNetzId` (although `AbstractIpCalculator` sounds like maybe it's missing the `=0` for the method that should be implemented in the derived class?)

Comment: Yes, the code for setCommunicationNumber and setParkNetzId is wirtten in AbstractIpCalculator. calculate is a virtual QString calculate(QString) = 0; defined in AbstractIpCalculator. I used this class but it i can't use it in my unit test and i have no clue whye

Comment: I suspect you've forgotten the implementation file where the functions are defined.

Comment: Hm, I dont know where i have forgotten to implement it?? I already use this class. I have updated the question, maybe it helps?

Comment: I don't see a `ComboxOne.cpp` somewhere in the project file, that's the sort of thing I was referring to in the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you have not got `ComboxOne` in the `Unittest.pro` file.

Comment: I thought it would be enough if this file is in the include path.

What do I need to write in my project file? The file is relative in ../../../classes/ip_calculator/comboxone

Comment: Source files like a `.cpp` file are not "included", they are compiled. To compile it, it needs to be in the `SOURCES` list in the project file.

Comment: Many many many thanks! It works now. Could you tell me what the include path is for?

Comment: For the compiler to find the header files that you include. And I'm going to write down the conclusion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the `ComboxOne.cpp` not being listed in `SOURCES`. Since the project file is essentially a makefile, and the linking phase of the build is based on `SOURCES`, if a required source file is not present, the linker will not find the symbols...

Comment: There are many questions concerning the link error in test lib. This is the best answer!